# 'function' object is not subscriptable error message

Tags: python, function

I am new to python and I am trying to make a basic text game with an inventory system. It was all going perfectly until I realised I needed the whole inv system as a function instead, and that's where the problems started.

```
gloinv = ["apple (food) 5", "health (healthpotion) 10", "sword (weapon) 5"]
hunger = 5
health = 10
fighting = False
enemyLife = 0

def get_num(x):
    return (int(''.join(ele for ele in x if ele.isdigit())))

def inv():
    global gloinv
    global inv
    print(gloinv)
    while True:
        item = input("which item would you like to select?  ")
        select = inv[int(item)-1]
        print("you have selected '", select,"'")
        use = input("type 'use' to use it or 'back' to select another.  ")
        if use == "use":
            if "(food)" in select:
                y = (int(''.join(ele for ele in select if ele.isdigit())))
                print("you have eaten", (select.split(' ', 1)[0] ), "your hunger is now", hunger + y)
                inv.remove(select)
                print(inv)
                gloinv = inv
                break
            elif "(healthpotion)" in select:
                y = (int(''.join(ele for ele in inv[int(item)-1] if ele.isdigit())))
                print("you have drunk", (inv[int(item)-1].split(' ', 1)[0] ), "your health is now", health + y)
                health = health + y
                inv.remove(inv[int(item)-1])
                print(inv)
                gloinv = inv
                break
            elif "weapon" in inv[int(item)-1]:
                if fighting == True:
                    enemyLife - get_num(inv[int(item)-1])
                elif fighting == True:
                    print("you can't use a weapon here")
                break
        elif use == "back":
            print(inv)

inv()
print(gloinv)
print(hunger)
print(health)
```

I've tried to adapt to some problems but when I run this it comes up with;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jenson\Desktop\Python\inv.py", line 47, in <module>
    inv()
  File "C:\Users\Jenson\Desktop\Python\inv.py", line 19, in inv
    select = inv[int(item)-1]
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
enter code here
>>>
```

I have looked on other questions on this site but they are too confusing for me and tailored to different code doing different things.

Comment: `inv` is a function.  `function[...]` doesn't mean anything

Comment: As the error says, you can't subscript a function. `inv` is a function, what do you expect `inv[int(item)-1]` to do? Did you mean `gloinv[int(item)-1]`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers but I found the solution doing some testing of my own. What I did wrong was label the function (inv) the same thing as the variable (inv) I solved it by naming the variable vInv instead so python wouldn't confuse the two.

Answer (score -1):

Use parentheses (`()`) and not brackets (`[]`) when making a function call.

Comment: `inv` doesn't take arguments, so this can't be the problem.

Comment: Won't help, since `gloinv = inv`.

Comment: Mm, no clue then. OP needs to clarify the intent.

Answer (score -1):

On line 19, you are doing the following:

`select = inv[int(item)-1]`

First of all; it's not clear what the purpose of this is. Please double check it. If you want to call the `inv` function, you need to call it with parentheses `()` and add the method parameters to the function declaration. Right now you're **treating a function as a list**, and using `int(item)-1` as the index of that list. Hence the error.

Comment: Thanks, but I found a solution doing some testing of my own. I had called the function the same thing as the variable and python was getting confused.

Comment: @Jenson42 Can you accept an answer as correct if it helped? Do it in the future for your next questions too!